# Using command to compute sum?

Tags: macros, calculations

I must admit this sounds like an easy question.

I'm creating a grading model for a homework assignment, and I'm adding the maximum amount of points to each question. Is there a way to have LaTeX print out the sum of these (integer) points automatically?

```
\points{3} Solve equation [...]
\points{5} Give proof of [...]

Max points: \totalpoints{}
```

That would then print out *"Max points: 8"* at the end of the document.

Comment: You may take a look at the [exam](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually very simple using a normal LaTeX counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{points}
\newcommand*{\points}[1]{\addtocounter{points}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\totalpoints}{\thepoints}% Or simply use `\thepoints` directly.

\begin{document}

\points{3} Solve equation [...]
\points{5} Give proof of [...]

Max points: \totalpoints{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if this is interesting at all, and it's complete [overkill](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/overkill-is-a-good-thing/). It is just a very simple example of using Lua code in a LaTeX document.

Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newcommand\points[1]{%
\luaexec{
  if a == nil then
    a = #1
  else
    a = a + #1
  end
}}
\newcommand\totalpoints{\luaexec{tex.sprint(a)}}

\begin{document}
\points{3} Solve equation [...]
\points{5} Give proof of [...]

Max points: \totalpoints{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Examples like this will gain new LuaTeX fans. Really.

Answer (score 8):

The `exam` class provides the command `\numpoints` which will calculate the total points for you.

See the documentation for full details- a MWE follows

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

%\pointsdroppedatright          % try uncommenting this line
%\pointpoints{point}{points}

\cfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage {} of \numpages} 
\lfoot{\footnotesize TOTAL POINTS : \numpoints\ }

This exam has \numquestions\ questions, for a total of \numpoints\ points. The number of points for each  part is given in brackets.

\begin{questions}
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++
%   QUESTION
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++
\question[10] What is your favourite fruit?

\vspace{\fill}

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++
%   QUESTION
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++
\question[23] What is the answer?

\vspace{\fill}
\droppoints

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice because it allows you to state the number of points *before* the questions. However, I have a bit too much other markup and environments to conform to the exam template, so I picked the simple solution.

Comment: @Noio: No problem! It's well worth investigating the `exam` class for future projects :)