# Practical use of Lua

Tags: lua

Although I always use LuaLaTeX to compile my documents, I don't really use [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) that often. Sometimes I even forget about it.

In my last document I used it to write a random word generator, which picks a word from a pool of words. Which can be really helpful in many different documents and circumstances. I came up with this code in another question, but I will repost it here, if someone wants to use it.

So today I asked myself, what are some other good uses for Lua in TeX documents? And here we go, now it's your turn to post your ideas.

---

Thanks for all the great answers. There are some great ideas, and I certainly can put them to good use in my own documents (and other users aswell, I guess :) ). In my opinion, every answer deserves the check mark, so I guess I will let the community decide and choose the one with the most upvotes.

That of course doesn't mean you have to stop posting your awesome ideas ;)

Comment: Lua is a Turing-complete programming language, so it's usage is... everything.

Comment: Yes of course, but I wanted to know when and why you use it in your documents. Not when you just use lua...

Comment: Not a direct answer, but just take a look on the book by Herbert Voss: LuaLaTeX, with many examples.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks, I didn't know this one.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70. Also, not sure if these two count as 'good', but I'll mention them anyway: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35676/using-command-to-compute-sum/35694#35694 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36572/parse-simple-arithmetics-and-return-the-result/36735#36735

Comment: I think the greatest benefit of using LuaLaTeX from a user perspective is having packages like `selnolig` or `impnattypo`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer can you provide a link to the book on amazon or whatever? I can't seem to find it!

Comment: @Vishesh: I'll try, but I am unsure, whether the book is available so far only in German... http://www.amazon.de/Einf%C3%BChrung-LuaTeX-LuaLaTeX-Herbert-Vo%C3%9F/dp/386541530X/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1408720984&sr=8-4&keywords=Herbert+Voss... so far in German only

Comment: @m0nhawk TeX is a Turing-complete language on his own.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Yes, but not a very useful in this role.

Comment: @m0nhawk Well, *you* based your argumentation on Lua being Turing-complete, not I. :) Interesting aspects of Lua may well lie somewhere else.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald but some of them are *more* Turing-complete, than other. Some of them more applicable than the others.

Comment: @m0nhawk Your initial argument is not that Lua is *more* Turing-complete than TeX is. Lua is a generalist extension language whose imperative paradigm is common and well understood while TeX is a specialised language focused on typesetting, which strange programming paradigm sits somewhere between M4 and machine language.  If this is what you mean, nothing prevents you to put it this way. This would look like useful bits of information.

Comment: I'd like to link to the Sieve of Erasthones question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44748/86 The lua answer works far, far faster than a TeX version would do.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: May I suggest the [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378)? :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

LaTeX can not do all things you might want to typeset. Sometimes you might need the power of another (scripting) language. You are free to use Perl, PHP, bash scripts or what ever. But the main advantage of Lua is very simple - it's available. On all supported platforms. No need for the user to install anything else!

In my [`getmap`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/getmap) package, I use a Lua script to connect web servers to download maps:

[image]

```
% compile with pdflatex -shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% use overwrite while optimizing the image
\usepackage[overwrite,mode=gm]{getmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{berlin.epl}
&path=weight:5|color:purple|enc:_xq_IcgrpA?AFE@?^BFE@A^U@CLQXEZU?gCR?B?DBF@@?vA?D?D?BAHE@JBN@JLGFCG[DC~C?@?F?R?vA?p@iB@i@Fe@JWRSTOf@Gh@C^A?e@?gE?w@r@?lB@hA?`@??M?aA?]dI??O?O?Cn@cBfBeF|AeEHNVNBc@H@H_AEwA?OAMNA@N
\end{filecontents*}
\getmap[file=berlin, language=de, xsize=400, ysize=600,
        markers={&markers=size:mid|label:H|color:green|Berlin, Hbf
                 &markers=label:B|color:blue|Brandenburger Tor, Berlin},
        pathfile={berlin.epl}]{}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{berlin}
\end{document}
```

The route was exported into a `gpx file` and converted to encoded polylines (Google's route format) by the very same Lua script:

```
getmapdl -m gpx2epl -G berlin.gpx
```

So, from my point of view, the **embedded** Lua interpreter opens new horizons!

Comment: It looks a very nice package!

Comment: `compile with pdflatex`?

Comment: Why not? ;-) `-shell-escape` is the important part! If you want to use `lua` in your document, then it works only with `lualatex`. OTOH, `getmap` calls an external `lua` script, which means the script is executed with `texlua`. That's the `lua` interpreter of `luatex`. This works for all engines including `pdflatex`. But it needs the `-shell-escape` switch to allow the execution of external scripts.

Comment: Somewhat related, nowadays there's `lt3luabridge` to call Lua code from pdftex which wraps the manual write18.

Answer (score 28):

The latest version of Tikz supports automatic graph layout with LuaTeX. When the appropriate TikZ options are given, a selection of Lua scripts are invoked that receive the structure of the graph and compute the positions of the nodes. A variety of automatic graph layout algorithms are supported. The API for writing your own algorithm in Lua is also documented in the manual. C/C++ is also supported through the runtime dynamic linking feature of Lua itself.

Example from the manual (note the `layered layout` option):

[image: graph example]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.spaced,graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\tikz [nodes={text height=.7em, text depth=.2em,
              draw=black!20, thick, fill=white, font=\footnotesize},
       >=spaced stealth', rounded corners, semithick]
  \graph [layered layout, level distance=1cm, sibling sep=.5em, sibling distance=1cm] {
    "5th Edition" -> { "6th Edition", "PWB 1.0" };
    "6th Edition" -> { "LSX" [>child anchor=45], "1 BSD", "Mini Unix", "Wollongong", "Interdata" };
    "Interdata" -> { "Unix/TS 3.0", "PWB 2.0", "7th Edition" };
    "7th Edition" -> { "8th Edition", "32V", "V7M", "Ultrix-11", "Xenix", "UniPlus+" };
    "V7M" -> "Ultrix-11";
    "8th Edition" -> "9th Edition";
    "1 BSD" -> "2 BSD" -> "2.8 BSD" -> { "Ultrix-11", "2.9 BSD" };
    "32V" -> "3 BSD" -> "4 BSD" -> "4.1 BSD" -> { "4.2 BSD", "2.8 BSD", "8th Edition" };
    "4.2 BSD" -> { "4.3 BSD", "Ultrix-32" };
    "PWB 1.0" -> { "PWB 1.2" -> "PWB 2.0", "USG 1.0" -> { "CB Unix 1", "USG 2.0" }};
    "CB Unix 1" -> "CB Unix 2" -> "CB Unix 3" -> { "Unix/TS++", "PDP-11 Sys V" };
    { "USG 2.0" -> "USG 3.0", "PWB 2.0", "Unix/TS 1.0" } -> "Unix/TS 3.0";
    { "Unix/TS++", "CB Unix 3", "Unix/TS 3.0" } -> "TS 4.0" -> "System V.0" -> "System V.2" -> "System V.3";
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the lua scripts use GraphViz?

Comment: @MartinSchröder no, they use similar algorithms, but all calculations are done by lua

Answer (score 24):

LuaTeX provides all kinds of new hooks into the innards of TeX's operations. The paragraph-building algorithm, for one, has been opened up in several, very useful ways. This functionality enables the creation of new packages that do all kinds of stuff that simply wasn't possible before.

For instance, the [selnolig](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig) package -- which performs selective suppression of typographic ligatures, for both German and English language texts, *without* the need for either tedious hand mark-up or the running of a pre-processor -- depends crucially on various LuaTeX callbacks to do its job. Without LuaTeX, this package would simply not exist. (Full disclosure: I'm the main author of this package.)

Answer (score 22):

This may be thought of an extended comment to phg's answer. As an academic, I need to maintain multiple versions of my CV. For examples, one version of the CV must include all the publications, another should only include publications in the last five years, and another publications in the last six years! One should include a table that lists all grants and specify the amount of funding each year, the other only a list of grants with just the total amount mentioned. There are similar requirements for other fields of the CV.

In summary, the same data needs to be filtered differently and presented differently for each version. Manually maintaining multiple versions is an error-prone task. So, here is what I do (using ConTeXt):

1. All the data goes into different XML files. One file for publications, one for grants, etc. The advantage is that validate the data using standard XML tools.
2. Use the ConTeXt XML library to convert the XML file into Lua tables.
3. Create Lua functions to filter data from the Lua tables. For example, one function discards all publications that is more than `n` years old, another adds the grant amount for each year to compute the total amount, etc.
4. Create Lua functions to typeset according to each requirement. These are written in the CLD (ConTeXt Lua Document) format.
5. Now each version of the CV is easy to maintain. For example one has

   ```
   \startluacode
      cv.list_of_publications("journal", "all")
   \stopluacode
   ```

   while the other has

   ```
   \startluacode
      cv.list_of_publications("journal", 6)
   \stopluacode
   ```

   and so on.

In principle, it is possible to do all this by programming in TeX as well. After all, TeX is Turing complete. But it is much easier to do this with XML + Lua.

It is also possible to use any standard programming language to do this task. After all, every language has an XML parser, and CLD interface is easy to replicate with a well thought out TeX library. However, with such an interface all communication between the library and TeX takes place through text files. If something goes wrong, then debugging can be a pain. Ask anyone who has tried to debug why TeX labels do not appear in MP files!

Comment: I'd love to see examples for this workflow.  Do you know any good resources?

Answer (score 19):

Taking the question seriously, here are a few examples from the Context
sources†:

- [The new bibliography system, finally obsoleting Bibtex.](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/publ-ini.lua)
- [The web server](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/scripts/context/lua/mtx-server.lua)
  that powers [the Pragma ADE website](http://pragma-ade.com).
- [Multi-purpose registers](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/strc-reg.lua)
  from which e. g. indices are derived.
- Various parsers for
  [CSV](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/util-prs.lua),
  [JSON](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/util-jsn.lua)
  and other common formats (for Latex provided by the `lualibs` package).
- [A complete XML parser](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/lxml-tab.lua),
  the foundation of Context’s exceptional XML support.
- [CLD](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/cldf-ini.lua)
  -- you won’t believe how awesome it is until you try it.
  See also [the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/cld).
- [The SQL interface.](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/util-sql.lua).
- ... *many more*! I encourage you to explore the Context distribution.
  Particularly the directories

  - `tex/context/base/`
  - `scipts/context/lua`

  in the TEXMF.

† *Note that much of the functionality is spread over multiple files. I only
linked the entry points / main files in these cases.*

Comment: Saying that is **the** new bibliography system is misleading (and possibly mischievous?) since `biber` and `biblatex` are also a new bibliography system. (Whether they make bibtex obsolete is another matter.) Neither of these (nor other alternatives) can be accurately described as **the** new system. They are each **a** new system.

Comment: @cfr neither Biber nor Biblatex work with Context, and Bibtex outside of Latex was always a hack. So, yes, it is in fact *the* new bibliography system, as far as Context is concerned.

Comment: But the question is about *Lua* and **not** about ConTeXt specifically. Since we have LuaLaTeX, `biber` and `biblatex` is definitely a Lua-compatible system. I stand by the claim: it is inaccurate to claim that system is **the** new system in the context of this question. Indeed, since the question mentions LuaLaTeX, if anything, `biber` + `biblatex` is **the** new bibliographic system in this context.

Comment: @cfr -- The answer clearly uses the word ConTeXt in the first sentence.  I think the "context" is pretty clear.  (Though I'm not arguing against edits.)  But `Biber` (Perl) and `biblatex` (LaTeX) have no necessary tie to Lua, so they should *not* be mentioned.

Comment: @jon I'm not suggesting they should be mentioned. I'm only disagreeing with the use of the definite article in the answer and, to me, that use combined with the comment about bibTeX clearly suggests that the link is *the* new bibliography system (and that this is one of the listed advantages of conTeXt).

Comment: Some of the links are broken. Maybe a check is in order.